# Can I deploy a container registry and host a HTTPS webserver on the same system?

Tags: docker, ssl

I am running a HTTPS webserver. On the same host, I would like to run a docker container registry.

According to [this tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/#run-an-externally-accessible-registry), I need to run this command:

```
 docker run -d \
  --restart=always \
  --name registry \
  -v "$(pwd)"/certs:/certs \
  -e REGISTRY_HTTP_ADDR=0.0.0.0:443 \
  -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/certs/domain.crt \
  -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY=/certs/domain.key \
  -p 443:443 \
  registry:2
```

But my nginx server already has 443 bound. So I guess I can't run the container registry with this port. What are my options here? Can I just use something other than 443?

Answer (score 1):

You could use Nginx as a proxyserver and have (sub)domains pointing to the two different services (Webserver and Docker Container Registry)

#### Step 1 : Set up domainnames

- DNS: registry.mycompany.com to IP address of the Host
- DNS: [www.mycompany.com](http://www.mycompany.com) to IP address of the Host

#### Step 2 : Config Nginx as a proxyserver

##### Nginx sites.conf

```bash
# Main Server
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}



# The Webserver
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name www.mycompany.com;

    ssl_certificate         /etc/ssl/private/star_mycompany_com.chained.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/ssl/private/star_mycompany_com.key;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/webserver_access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/webserver_error.log;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://172.30.0.3:80/;
    }
}

# The Registry
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name registry.mycompany.com;

    ssl_certificate         /etc/ssl/private/star_mycompany_com.chained.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/ssl/private/star_mycompany_com.key;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/registry_access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/registry_error.log;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://172.30.0.2:80/;
    }
}
```

In your docker-compose.yml of the registry, put it on IP 172.30.0.2,

and in the docker-compose.yml of the webserver, put it on IP 172.30.0.3

#### Step 3 : Run Nginx itself in a Docker Container

##### docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: "3.9"

services:
  proxyserver:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: Proxyserver
    working_dir: /usr/share/nginx/html
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./etc/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d:ro
      - ./etc/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
      - ./etc/ssl/private:/etc/ssl/private
      - ./var/log/nginx:/var/log/nginx
    networks:
      my-net:
        ipv4_address: 172.30.0.254

networks:
  my-net:
    external: true
    name: cops-net
```

#### Step 4 : Create your external Docker Network

##### create_network.sh

```bash
docker network create \
    --driver=bridge \
    --subnet=172.30.0.0/16 \
    --attachable \
    --gateway=172.30.0.1 \
    my-net
```

#### Step 5 : Start everything up

- Start the container with the webserver
- Start the container with the registry
- Start the proxyserver

Comment: The SSL certificate I bought for my domain is specifically for `site.mydomain.com`. Can I use that certificate for e.g. `registry.mydomain.com`?

Comment: It depends what kind of certificate you bought. If it is a wildcard certificate, you can use it for all subdomains. It it is a specific certificate (for 1 subdomain only), then you need to change the sites.conf accordingly. See the 3rd line in the volumes section of the docker-compose. There I map a whole directory, currently containing 2 wildcard certificates. But you can put in there what you want, like a certificate for every subdomain.

Comment: It is a specific certificate. If I understand you correctly, I need to buy another certificate for this to work.

Comment: There are different kind of certificates. The solution I showed works with all kinds of certificates. However, you might need to change the scripts dependant of the type of certificate you have. WildCard Certificate: Just put the same certificate in all Containers. Subdomein-specific certificate: Each Container needs its own certificate.